# Array as folders

Tags: php, arrays, directory

I did this code:
index.php:

```
$series = array(
    "a" => array(
        "b" => array(
            "FOLD", "more_arrays.php"
        ),
        "b2" => array(
        )
    )
);

function pre($a) { print "<pre>"; print_r($a); print "</pre>"; }
$string = "a,,,b";

$all_directions = explode(",,,", $string);
$all_directions = array_map("trim", $all_directions);

$b = ""; $g = 0;
foreach($all_directions as $v)
{
    $b .= "['".str_replace(array("[", "]", "'", "\""), null, $v)."']";
    $g++;
}

@eval('$where = $series'.$b.';');

if(isset($where[0]) && $where[0] == "FOLD")
{
    // a[series], b[series], c[new_array]
    require_once("./more_folders/".$where[1]);

    print $g;
}

for($i = 0; $i <= sizeof($where); $i++)
{
}

pre($where);
```

more_array.php:

```
$series_in = array(
    "c" => array(
        "d" => array(
            "bla" => array(),
            "hey" => array(),
            "ha" => array()
        ),
        "d2" => array(

        )
    ),
    "c2" => array(
    )
)
```

At $string I define which "folder" I want to see, for example if I write `$string = "a";` it will show all the arrays inside "a".

key = the name of the folder, value = the subfolders inside the folder and those array.

Now: Because it's going to be a huge array, I want to separate it to many arrays.
If you see at the code, `$series[a][b]` direct lead to another array.

Now if I do `$string = "a,,,b";` I want to see: "c" and "c2"
and if I do `$string = "a,,,b,,,c";` I want to see: "d", "d2"
and if I do `$string = "a,,,b,,,c,,,d";` I want to see all inside d ( "bla", "hey", "ha" ..)

How can I do this?

Comment: bleeee. @eval('$where = $series'.$b.';');

Comment: Please clarify your question (if there is one at all).

Comment: I want to do that when i write $string = "a,,b,,c"; it will research at $series_in

Comment: It seems to be very complicated, what do you need to do ? What represents your series and your searched string ? Could you explain your idea...

Answer (score 0):

I'll bite...

You seem to have most of the parts. Basically you need to put them together in a loop.

You've `$string` and `$series`. Then you split `$string` into your `$all_directions`. Loop thru `$all_directions`, each time diving down into the array `$series = $series[$all_directions[$i]];` When you've done the last `$all_directions` return `$series` (but watch for running out of `$series`, return null, or false if you're sure that would be an error).

The only other thing is any time `$series[$all_directions[$i]]` is the special "FOLD" entry then first load the file and assign it on-the-fly something like
`include ...;
$series[$all_directions[$i]] = $series_in;`

You don't want and don't need `eval()` and the loop is better using `for` because you need to check `"FOLD"` in the key (I'd also say use a recursive function but you said the array can be very big so it might hurt performance).